# Bulma: Select and Input next to each other with the same width

Tags: css, bulma

I am trying to position a select and input field with the same width next to each other.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.9.1/css/bulma.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="field-body">
  <div class="field is-fullwidth">
    <input class="input" type="number" placeholder="Name">
  </div>
  <div class="field has-addons">
    <div class="control is-expanded">
      <div class="select is-fullwidth">
        <select style="flex-basis: 0">
          <option>Choose..</option>
          <option>...</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But it is already working, right? Are you trying to say it should also work on smaller screens? or do you want to reduce their widths?

Comment: atm the input field is widther than the select field

Comment: Then you can wrap them inside columns: https://vee2p.csb.app/

Answer (score 0):

last example on [bulma form doc](https://bulma.io/documentation/form/general/#horizontal-form):

```
 <div class="field is-horizontal">  
  <div class="field-body">
    <div class="field">
      <p class="control is-expanded has-icons-left">
        <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="Name">
        <span class="icon is-small is-left">
          <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
        </span>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <p class="control is-expanded has-icons-left has-icons-right">
        <input class="input is-success" type="email" placeholder="Email" value="">
        <span class="icon is-small is-left">
          <i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>
        </span>
        <span class="icon is-small is-right">
          <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
        </span>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```